# Akka Machine Failure

Tags: amazon-ec2, akka, failover

I would like to know if a machine on Akka cluster goes down (Amazon EC2 Spot Instances), how to re-route same messages in the mailboxes of actors running on this Inntance to Same actor instances running on another machine.

Thanks.

-Devendra

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use something like the work pulling pattern to track work dispatched to remote nodes.  Once a message is in an actor's mailbox, it's lost if that actor crashes.

http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2

http://blog.conspire.com/post/64901258135/akka-at-conspire-part-5-the-importance-of (I wrote this one)